# How I can get all similar words from database to array?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli, pdo

I have simple table in my database:

[image]

And I get using my function similar words from my table:

```
function similar_words($array, $conn){
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE ?');
        $query->execute(array("%$value%"));
        while ($results = $query->fetch())
        {
            if(!in_array($results['word'], $result)) $result[] = $results['word'];
        }
    } 
    return $result;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
similar_words(['app','sql'], $pdo);
```

It take this result in output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => app
    [2] => apple
    [3] => appstore
    [7] => postgresql
    [8] => sql
    [9] => mysqli
)
```

But if I add to my array words for query to database using incorrect words it can't take me needed result for me:

```
similar_words(['myql','sl','eson','ptor'], $pdo);
```

Here in array `"myql"` from `"mysqli"`, `"sl"` from `"sql"`,`"mysqli"` or `"postgresql"`, `"eson"` from `"lesson"` and `"ptor"` from `"appstore"`.  How I can using that words get in result array with similarity words from database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysqli
    [1] => appstore
    [2] => sql
    [3] => postgresql
    [4] => lesson
)
```

I did create this function and database for example and in my real database have words more 100000 in UTF-8. And can be optimized my function? Thanks for answers!

Comment: Step 2 will literally contain everything step 1 and step 3 contains, and is the only step you need. The `%` symbol can also mean "nothing", so every case is considered with `%$value%`

Comment: So I can skip the second step? @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: No. _Keep_ only the 2nd step. Get rid of step 1 and 3, you only need 1 query for this.

Comment: Ok thanks @GrumpyCrouton ). But how I get last result using query? Can be used levenshtein in query?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You just want the last result in the array? You could just do `echo $array[count($array)-1];`

Comment: I should choose similar words from the database or those words in which there are those letters that are in the word passed in the array @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159510/discussion-between-grumpycrouton-and-max-net).

Comment: Or, use Levenshtein to query the database in some way to get similar words from the database.

Comment: I think your best option would be to loop through the results and use [`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: I can't using levenshtein in mysql query? For me, the main thing now is optimization and performance of the function. If I take all words from  database, then this will be a load for the operative memory of the computer.

Comment: How I can use this [function](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=552) for take all similar words from db?

Comment: This kind of task belongs in specialized code, not in SQL.